# How to use Kafka Streams to Split Messages into Slow and Fast Tracks

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream of messages to be processed by an app written in Kafka streams, small subset of those messages require external DB lookups to be processed.

I believe this DB is too big to be streamed and too much to cache.
Is there a way to split the stream into to Fast and Slow streams so the slow one doesn't interfere with the fast one?

**I have thought of the following 3 options but I was hopping there might be sth simpler or more efficient:**

1) Let the messages be distributed evenly and since the volume of the ones that require reading from DB is low they wouldn't affect the overall throughput badly (latency is not a problem)

2) Use special key for the slow ones so they get assigned to one partition (I own the producer), but then it's hard to scale the slow ones and there is no guarantee that they will not interfere with the fast ones and it needs missing with producer.

3) Write the slow ones to as separate topic all together.

Comment: "too much to cache" - that's why a KTable isn't stored in heap. RocksDB would spill to disk

Comment: I would assume that option (3) would give you the most robust deployment.